# Cordova Media Plugin unable to open a file on ios

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, cordova-plugins, media

I am developing an audio player app using cordova on ios and android systems with cordova-plugin-media. Everything works fine on android version, but I am unable to open files on ios version. I am always getting error MediaError.MEDIA_ERR_ABORTED as seen on picture below:

[Link to the picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UBVuk.jpg)

And this is what i got from the console:

```
AppName[24042:1570281] Will attempt to use file resource 'file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7954CE22-7D19-4EFE-978F-A61E3CED4820/data/Containers/Data/Application/EBECDDE7-0415-4D1D-B152-F822FF320C49/Documents/products/92/Wielkie%20problemy%20ze%20snem%20malej%20slonicy%20Eli.mp3'
AppName[24042:1570281] Unknown resource 'file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7954CE22-7D19-4EFE-978F-A61E3CED4820/data/Containers/Data/Application/EBECDDE7-0415-4D1D-B152-F822FF320C49/Documents/products/92/Wielkie%20problemy%20ze%20snem%20malej%20slonicy%20Eli.mp3'
AppName[24042:1570281] THREAD WARNING: ['Media'] took '70.802002' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

i read mp3 files from dirs based on cordova.file.documentsDirectory. But the same problem exist when i change it to cordova.file.dataDirectory:

```
AppName[25764:1628569] Will attempt to use file resource 'file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7954CE22-7D19-4EFE-978F-A61E3CED4820/data/Containers/Data/Application/5CBC0692-AC00-42B4-BA9A-5A21EBBF19F8/Library/NoCloud/products/92/Wielkie%20problemy%20ze%20snem%20malej%20slonicy%20Eli.mp3'
AppName[25764:1628569] Unknown resource 'file:///Users/username/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/7954CE22-7D19-4EFE-978F-A61E3CED4820/data/Containers/Data/Application/5CBC0692-AC00-42B4-BA9A-5A21EBBF19F8/Library/NoCloud/products/92/Wielkie%20problemy%20ze%20snem%20malej%20slonicy%20Eli.mp3'
AppName[25764:1628569] THREAD WARNING: ['Media'] took '105.797607' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

This file exist, because I have access to it. It just can't be loaded by Media Plugin. Is there anything I can do to solve this problem?

Comment: just check whether you can try something like this link - https://github.com/gandhirajan/Cordova_File_Operations/blob/master/www/js/app.js

Comment: @Gandhi You mean LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT instead of cordova.file.documentsDirectory? Still not working. The same problem. And I noticed that cordova.file.documentsDirectory and LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT lead to the same directory where media plugin is unable to load.